# Insert line break in console.log output in Google Apps Script

Tags: arrays, google-apps-script

```
var arr = ['Day - 1 - ', 'Day - 2 - ', 'Day - 3 - ', 'Day - 4 - ', 'Day - 5'];

for (m = 0; m <= arr.length - 1; m++)
{
    console.log(arr[m].insert(' - ', '\n - '));
}
```

**Desired Result:**

> Day    Day    Day    Day    Day
>
> - 1 -  - 2 -  - 3 -  - 4 -  - 5 -

**ACTUAL RESULT:**

> No such function: insert

Is there an alternative to obtaining the desired result with Google Apps Script?

Thanks

I tried:

```
var arr = ['Day - 1 - ', 'Day - 2 - ', 'Day - 3 - ', 'Day - 4 - ', 'Day - 5'];

for (m = 0; m <= arr.length - 1; m++)
{
    console.log(arr[m].insert(' - ', '\n - '));
}
```

And got:
**ACTUAL RESULT:**

> No such function: insert

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my understanding, you want to log the array with line break. If it is correct, then one way is:

```
var arr = ['Day - 1 - ', 'Day - 2 - ', 'Day - 3 - ', 'Day - 4 - ', 'Day - 5'];
console.log(arr.join("\n"));
```

The log:

```
5:22:49 PM  Info    Day - 1 - 
                    Day - 2 - 
                    Day - 3 - 
                    Day - 4 - 
                    Day - 5
```

However to achieve your desired output in console, we shall split the strings in your array.

```
function myFunction() {

  var arr = ['Day - 1 - ', 'Day - 2 - ', 'Day - 3 - ', 'Day - 4 - ', 'Day - 5'];
  // split the srings
  var newArr = arr.map(str => str.split(" - "));

  console.log("newArr = ", newArr);
  // remove unnecessary spaces or blanks
  var newArr2 = newArr.map(r => r.filter(el => el !== " " && el !== ""));

  console.log("newArr2 = ", newArr2);
  
  console.log(newArr2.map(r => r[0]).join(" "));

  console.log(newArr2.map(r => r[1]).join("--"));

}
```

The log would be:

```
5:43:13 PM  Info    newArr =  [ [ 'Day', '1', '' ],
                                [ 'Day', '2', '' ],
                                [ 'Day', '3', '' ],
                                [ 'Day', '4', '' ],
                                [ 'Day', '5' ] ]
5:43:13 PM  Info    newArr2 =  [ [ 'Day', '1' ],
                                 [ 'Day', '2' ],
                                 [ 'Day', '3' ],
                                 [ 'Day', '4' ],
                                 [ 'Day', '5' ] ]
5:43:13 PM  Info    Day Day Day Day Day
5:43:13 PM  Info    1--2--3--4--5
```

I hope that it would be helpful to you.

Comment: That does it! Thanks. More involved than I thought probably why I was failing.